# asp.net/Dropdownlist: Upon selection of a ListItem I would like to allow to navigate some pages and restrict other pages

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I want to do it in a buttonclick at my first page
Button Click Event:

If (ddlistX.SelectedItem = "1" And **Some Hober button is selected**)

Navigate to page p1, p3 (restrict p2)

If (ddlistX.SelectedItem = "2" And **Some Hober button is selected**)

Navigate to page p1 and p2

else

message "Your selection is missing "

Any help  would be highly appreciatable

Answer (score -1, accepted):

(This is a modification of Ashwin's Answer)

> Hey Again: I have home,p2,p3 pages. condition 1 navigation:home>p3 condition 2 navigation: home>p2>p3

//condition 1

```
if (ddlistX.SelectedItem == "1" And ddlistY.SelectedItem == "a")
      { Session["p2.aspx"]=="True"; 
      Response.Redirect("p3.aspx"); //Navigate to page p3 and restrict p2 }
```

//condition 2

```
  else if (ddlistX.SelectedItem = ="2" ddlistY.SelectedItem == "b")
        { 
           Session["p2.aspx"]=="False"; 
          Response.Redirect(p2.aspx); Navigate to page p1 and p2 }
```

//I used postbackurl to navigate to p3 from p2

```
else { ErrorLabel.Text= "Your selection is missing "; }
```

In your p2 codebehind Page_Load, do this

```
if(Session["p2.aspx"]=="Yes") 
 { Response.Redirect("home.aspx"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (ddlistX.SelectedItem = "1" And Some Hober button is selected)
{
Session["Restrictp2"]=="Yes";
Response.Redirect(p1);
//Navigate to page p1, p3 (restrict p2)
}
else if (ddlistX.SelectedItem = "2" And Some Hober button is selected)
{
Session["Restrictp2"]=="No";
Response.Redirect(p1);
Navigate to page p1 and p2
}
else
{
ErrorLabel.Text= "Your selection is missing ";
}
```

In your p3 codebehind Page_Load, do this

```
if(Session["Restrictp2"].toString=="Yes")
{
Response.Redirect("home.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Thanks yaar, I am gonna try with this and let you know if works for me.

Comment: Thanks! it works with little correction,the first session condition 1 is ok and in the page load for p2 (actually) redirects to home page. but I didnt understand why did you use `Session["Restrictp2"]="No"` for?

Comment: On left side of my answer, you will see a 'tick', click on it.